# How can I make a certain int variable change in the following context

Tags: c#

For an experiment/practice, I am trying to let the user kill a dummy that has 100 hp, by dealing 25 damage off their hp every turn by pressing any key. The problem is that the output of the remainingHp int is 75 every time. How can I fix this? The code is as following:

```
        int dummyHP = 100;
        int charDmg = 25;
        int remainingHp = dummyHP - charDmg;

        Console.WriteLine("Start your journey by practicing your combat against a dummy.");
        void combat()
        {
                        
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start attacking");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Write("You attacked the dummy and the dummy's health points went down to: ");
            Console.WriteLine(remainingHp);         
        }

     
        while (remainingHp > 0)
        {
            combat();
        }
```

Comment: It seems like you want a line inside `combat` like `remainingHp = dummyHP - charDmg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```cs
remainingHp = remainingHp - charDmg;
```

after your `Console.ReadKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as is apparent is that you only decrease the remaining health once.

Going a bit OT here, I would advise you separate the presentantion layer from the logic, makes your code more elegant and easy to refactor, for example :

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/bvsaRuTz5)

```
// here a place the logic and the presentation in the same class for simplification sake,
// but of course you should separate these and possibly also use objects

using System;

class MyClass
{
    static int Combat(int remainingHp, int charDmg) // logic
    {
        return remainingHp -= charDmg;
    }

    static void PrintHealth(int remainingHp) // presentation
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start attacking");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine($"You attacked the dummy and the dummy's health points went down to {remainingHp}");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int remainingHp = 100;
        int charDmg = 25;
        Console.WriteLine("Start your journey by practicing your combat against a dummy.");

        do
        {
            remainingHp = Combat(remainingHp, charDmg);
            PrintHealth(remainingHp);
        } while (remainingHp > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int dummyHP = 100;
        int charDmg = 25;
        int remainingHp;

        Console.WriteLine("Start your journey by practicing your combat against a dummy.");
        void combat()
        {
        while (remainingHp > 0)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start attacking");
            Console.ReadKey();
            remainingHp = dummyHP - charDmg;

            Console.Write("You attacked the dummy and the dummy's health points went down to: ");
            Console.WriteLine(remainingHp);         
        }  
        }
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue, as `remainingHp` will always be set to `75`.

Comment: You're right in your context but I was suggesting using the global variable instead of local.